# Confusion related to gaussian integral

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

What is the integral of the following function:
$$\exp\left\{-\frac12y^T\Omega y - v^Ty\right\}$$ 
with respect to $dy$, where $\Omega$ is a positive definite matrix.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that $\Omega$ can be taken to be symmetric, it is also invertible because it is definite-positive. Make the change of variable: $x = y + \Omega^{-1} v$. Then, using the symmetry of $\Omega$, one can check that  $\frac{1}{2} x^T  \Omega x =  \frac{1}{2} y^T  \Omega y+ v^T y  + \frac{1}{2} (\Omega^{-1} v)^T(\Omega^{-1} v)$. Now you can use the standard result for Gaussian integration in $\mathbb{R}^n$: $$ \int e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^T \Omega x }dx = \sqrt{\frac{(2 \pi)^n}{\det\Omega}} $$

This leads to the result

$$ \int e^{-\frac{1}{2} y^T \Omega y - v^T y} = \sqrt{\frac{(2 \pi)^n}{\det\Omega}} e^{\frac{1}{2} v^T \Omega^{-2} v }$$